# How to create popup in cake php

Tags: cakephp

my question is about :I want to create a popup window in the same page with a transparent UI stuff and few buttons in that which cane be in the same action

Comment: You should use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try to search "modal" on Google. It running on Javascript and CSS